# Best imputation for principal component analysis

Tags: stata

I have a list of assets. I use these assets to create an asset index using pca:

```
local assets newspaper magazine clock water borehole table bed study bicycle cart car motorcycle tractor electricity fridge airconditioner fan washing_machine vacuum 
alpha $assets
pca $assets
predict asset_idx
label var asset_idx "pupil asset ownership index: created using pca"
egen asset_idx_std = std(asset_idx)
```

However, I am missing about 3% of assets for each variable. This amounts to 30% after pairwise deletion. As such, I wish to impute the missing variables so every student with less than 10% of observations missing is not deleted during PCA. I do not otherwise wish to mi set, but can't work out another way:

```
mi set wide
mi register imputed newspaper magazine clock water borehole table bed study bicycle cart car motorcycle tractor electricity fridge airconditioner fan washing_machine vacuum computer internet radio tv vcr dvd cd cassette camera digi_camera vid_cam landline phone

set seed 1234
mi impute logit newspaper magazine clock water borehole table bed study bicycle cart car motorcycle tractor electricity fridge airconditioner fan washing_machine vacuum computer internet radio tv vcr dvd cd cassette camera digi_camera vid_cam landline phone, force add(1)
```

Unfortunately, this is only successfully imputing a small fraction of missing observations:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
                   |               Observations per m             
                   |----------------------------------------------
          Variable |   Complete   Incomplete   Imputed |     Total
-------------------+-----------------------------------+----------
         newspaper |       7007          110         4 |      7117
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions on appropriate imputation are much appreciated.

Comment: Your code starts off by defining a local macro called `assets` but then calling a global macro with the same name. That might work if you have other definitions you don't specify.

Comment: Is it any better if you increase the number of imputations? Currently you've only got n=1 imputation (as specified by `add`).

Comment: Hi @NickCox, unfortunately using a different name for my global and local doesn't fix the problem. Neither does increasing the number of imputations.

Comment: I am not trying to fix your problem, just struggling to understand your code, which seems quite inconsistent. .